# No suma los elementos de un vector

Tags: java

Tengo un inconveniente a la hora de sumar elementos de un vector (no los suma e imprime cada elemento en vez de imprimir la suma total de los elementos) y no se qué está mal, espero me puedan ayudar!

Lo que quiero es que sume todos los elementos que haya ingresado y los imprima.

Ejemplo:

```
Ingrese la cantidad de elementos: 3
Ingrese valor: 2
Ingrese valor: 2
Ingrese valor: 2

La suma es: 6
```

```
package _Vector_Tamaño;
import java.util.Scanner;

/*
Desarrollar un programa que permita ingresar un vector de n elementos, ingresar n por teclado.
Luego imprimir la suma de todos sus elementos
*/

public class Problema1 {
private Scanner teclado;
private int[] elementos;
private int suma;

public void cargar() {
    teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n;
    System.out.print("Ingrese la cantidad de elementos: ");
    n = teclado.nextInt();
    elementos = new int[n];

    for(int f = 0; f < elementos.length; f++) {
        System.out.print("Ingrese valor: ");
        elementos[f] = teclado.nextInt();
    }
}

public void suma() {
    suma = 0;

    for(int f = 0; f < elementos.length; f++) {
        suma = suma + elementos[f];
    }

}

public void imprimir() {
    System.out.println("La suma es: " + suma);
}

public static void man(String[] ar) {
    Problema1 prob = new Problema1();
    prob.cargar();
    prob.suma();
    prob.imprimir();
}

}
```

Comment: puede aclarar cual es el comportamiento que quiere, no lo tengo muy claro ->  (no los suma e imprime cada elemento en vez de imprimir la suma total de los elementos) o quizas solo sea yo. Podria aclarar que esta obteniendo y que desea obtener. Saludos

Comment: He ejecutado tu código y no puedo reproducir el problema. A mi me sale la suma correctamente. Excepto por el error de tipeo en `main`

Comment: intente no cambiar el codigo a menos que sea nesesario, pues acabo de ver que el codigo no esta como estaba inicialmente. Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes un error de tipeo en `main`, Has puesto `man` en su lugar

Así sería corregido:

```
public static void main(String[] ar) {
    Problema1 prob = new Problema1();
    prob.cargar();
    prob.suma();
    prob.imprimir();
}
```

Fuera de esto el código está correcto y funciona de acuerdo a tu requerimiento. Parece ser que el problema no se puede reproducir

Comment: Gracias, era esto! Ya me estaba volviendo loco ver comentarios de que les funcionaba bien. Gracias de nuevo!

Comment: Si la respuesta te sirvió puedes marcarla como aceptada. Igual en tus otras 2 preguntas que has hecho previamente

Comment: Perdón que sea offtopic pero, cómo puedo marcarlas como aceptada? Gracias.

Comment: Con el check que sale debajo de las flechas para votar

Comment: Si deseas utilizar recursividad en la suma de todos los elementos del vector aquí el método: 
    public static int sumar(int[] vector, int pos) {
        return (pos == 0) ? vector[pos] : vector[pos] + sumar(vector, pos-1);
    }